# Galaxy S4 test app on real device

Tags: android, galaxy

Following the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html), I am trying to setup a testing environment on my S4. When I plug it into my computer the drivers do not install properly, so I follow the instructions to update it with whatever is in the `usb_driver` folder of the SDK.

I just get a message that says windows could not locate the driver and was unable to install, as if the correct driver isn't in the folder. I am clicking on SAMSUNG_Android under Other Devices in the Computer Management window. When I go to My Computer, I do see my device listed under Portable Devices though. Am I missing a step? Any help is appreciated

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

Comment: Development tool questions are explicitly on topic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download the USB Driver for Windows from here:

http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows